# Error: c2309 Struct Property not a Member of Struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

In the following code, I am getting the error: "'operation' is not a member of ExpStack::sNode". Hopefully I included enough to help solve the problem, if not let me know.

'operation' is declared in my struct so I don't see how i'm getting this error.

Structure.h:

```
class ExpStack {
public:
 //other stuff
 struct sNode {
    int data;
    String varName;

    opType operation;

    sNode(){
        data = 0;
        operation = NOP;
        varName = String("");
    };
 };
}
```

Structure.cpp:

```
void ExpStack::BuildStack(String& str){
  //other stuff
  sNode *temp = new sNode();
  if (next_token_type == SYMBOL){
      temp->operation = DetermineOpType(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the `typedef` as it is unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: Can you show what `opType` is? If you defined it using a macro you could cause this problem.

Comment: The code shown works fine for me exactly as shown (after adding the missing `BuildStack()` declaration, and the missing semicolon at the end of the class declaration).  The assignment of `operation` is fine, provided that `opType` is declared in the "other stuff" portion of `ExpStack` or is in global scope.

Comment: Thanks Remy! my opType wasn't in global scope.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/hOQruY) if I make up enough of the missing definitions to fix all the unrelated errors. Please post a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error you're seeing (and no other errors).